# Why is this query returning the database object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongohq

```
mongo.connect(mongostr, {}, function(error, db){ 
    var mycoll = db.collection("newuser"); 
    mycoll.find({'userID':12345}, 
                {'userID':true}, 
                function(err, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }); 
});
```

I've added a test collection to mongoDB, I know for a fact it's there. I know for a fact that exact query returns what I want (tested it myself in mongoHQ panel). mongo object works fine. Unfortunately the [docs don't have an example](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#making-queries-with-find), so I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

When the query runs I get a console dump of the db object:

```
 { db:     { databaseName: 'appxxxxxxx',
      serverConfig: 
       { host: 'staff.mongohq.com',
         port: 10096,
         options: {},
         internalMaster: true,
         connected: true,
         poolSize: 1,
         ssl: false,
         slaveOk: undefined,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.collection is an async call. You are accessing it in a synchronous fashion.

```
var mycoll = db.collection("newuser");
```

Try this:

```
mongo.connect(mongostr, {}, function(error, db){ 
    var mycoll = db.collection("newuser", function(err,collection){
             collection.find({'userID':12345}, 
                {'userID':true}, 
                function(err, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: That's deep. Why is it if I swap in .findOne() it works even though I use db.collection() synchronously?